# Python: sorting a list of tuples on alpha case-insensitive order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of tuples ("twoples")

```
[('aaa',2), ('BBB',7), ('ccc',0)]
```

I need to print it in that order, but

```
>>> sorted([('aaa',2), ('BBB',7), ('ccc',0)])
```

gives

```
[('BBB', 7), ('aaa', 2), ('ccc', 0)]

list.sort(key=str.tolower)
```

doesn't work (obviously), because

```
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'tolower'
```

I don't want to change the strings in the list.

Another answer gave

```
list.sort(key=lambda (a, b): (a.lower(), b))
```

but that must be a Python 2 thing, because

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

... at the first (

itemgetter() doesn't help, because there's only one 'key' allowed

Answer (score 8):

You're right that this is a Python 2 thing, but the fix is pretty simple:

```
list.sort(key=lambda a: (a[0].lower(), a[1]))
```

That doesn't really seem any less clear, because the names `a` and `b` don't have any more inherent meaning than `a[0]` and `a[1]`. (If they were, say, `name` and `score` or something, that might be a different story…)

---

Python 2 allowed you to unpack function arguments into tuples. This worked (and was sometimes handy) in some simple cases, but had a lot of problems. See [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) for why it was removed.

The canonical way to deal with this is to just split the value inside the function, which doesn't quite work in a `lambda`. But is there a reason you can't just define the function out of line?

```
def twoplekey(ab):
    a, b = ab
    return a.lower(), b

list.sort(key=twoplekey)
```

---

As a side note, you really shouldn't call your list `list`; that hides the `list` type, so you can't use it anymore (e.g., if you want to convert a tuple to a list by writing `list(tup)`, you'll be trying to call your list, and get a baffling error).

Comment: I almost got it with my first  lambda expression  -  I didn't think of putting both a and b in.  Both your solutions work perfectly (and now I can extend them to more complex cases).
I think the answer to your lat question is: the function (like the lambda expression) is applied to each row of the list.
(I only called it "list" to show that I'm working with a list.)

Comment: PS:   I just tried it with a dict (using 'D=dict(mylist)', and no surprise, it works as well.

Comment: @ZZMike: Yes, my point is that a function defined out-of-line with `def`, like a function defined in-line with `lambda`, can be just as easily applied to each row of the list. So, if you can't figure out how to write something with `lambda`, you can always use `def` (which allows you to include assignments and other statements).

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Python 3:

```
>>> my_list = [('aaa',2), ('BBB',7), ('ccc',0)]
>>> my_list.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[0].lower())
>>> print(my_list)
[('aaa', 2), ('BBB', 7), ('ccc', 0)]
```

The function argument unpacking doesn't work in Python 3 (as you have discovered), but from the phrasing of the question it looks like you only care about the comparison of the first element (`elem[0]`) of each tuple. This example concentrates on that and ignores the second element (`elem[1]`).